# Why is this not a contradiction to the existence and uniqueness theorem of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given:
$$y'=(x-y)^2, y(0)=0$$

I substituted $z=x-y$ which gives $$\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right) = x$$

So the solution is: $$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x-y}{1-x+y}\right) = x$$

This is defined in a small neighborhood of $(0,0)$.
But the function $y \equiv 0$ is also a solution.

So, Why is this not a contradiction to the [Existence and uniqueness theorem of an ODE](https://file:///home/shir/Downloads/Dialnet-FromScalarsToScalesAnOverviewOfLocalExistenceAndLo-8025335.pdf)

Thanks

Comment: $y\equiv 0$ is not a solution.

Comment: A comment aside: $y\equiv 0$ is not the identity function.